# Is there any place to get browser and version usage by industry?

Tags: user-research, browser

The company I work for is investigating creating a new product which will be a web application used within hospitals. I am attempting to get concrete numbers on how many hospitals (or percentage of hospitals) are running various OS and browsers (i.e. what % is still using IE6, vs IE7). In general I'm surprised I haven't found anything which grouped browser usage by industry, is anyone familiar with a resource like that?

Comment: Related: [Industry Standards for Browser Support?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57660/industry-standards-for-browser-support)

Comment: Perhaps http://marketshare.hitslink.com/ might have a proprietary report ($$$) with that information.

Comment: Note that enterprises still supporting old browsers tend to do so because they have old enterprise software that only supported said old browsers. So it's not so much what they use now that is of concern but what they *could* use now if their enterprise software supported it in the first place.

Comment: @TScott thanks for the link, I'll look into whether or not they can provide the data we need.

Comment: @DA01 the software we are making is a much smaller piece of the total landscape that a hospital has. We aren't going to be competing with Epic anytime soon, so we just don't have the weight to force upgrades. I appreciate the sentiment though.

Comment: @LukeBearl that's not quite what I meant. I meant that a hospital may be using IE7 only because they still have to support some crappy other software. That doesn't *preclude* them from allowing the latest Chrome, though...it's just since their enterprise software doesn't use it, they may not report much Chrome use. But your software could still certainly be used on Chrome. For example, our company would report 90% of our traffic from IE10 due to crappy enterprise software...but we can all use Chrome as well.

Comment: There are proprietary reports available to answer this question.  It's worth noting that the answers to this question can depend on type of user (clinical, administrative), type of hospital (academic, community), location (urban, rural), and other factors. It's also worth noting that that hospitals tend to have very locked-down environments, so a single supported browser is often all that is available to (some) users.  All that said, I think @Dipak is right and this isn't a UX question as currently stated.

Comment: If you can't find the data yourself, you could always see what other health care apps are being developed for. I'm sure your going to have difficulty finding the answer to this, there are just to many things to consider.